# Django - Filter based on nested sum of related values

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I have 3 Django models like this

`Request` is a donation request, `RequestItem` denotes how many instances of the `name` item are needed, `Donation` denotes how many donations have been done for the connected `item`

```
class Request:
    pass


class RequestItem:
    name
    request = ForeignKey(Request)
    needed = IntegerField()


class Donation:
    item = ForeignKey(RequestItem)
    donated = IntegerField()
```

A RequestItem a is said to be complete if

a.needed == Sum(donation.donated for each donation in a.donation_set.all()

A Request r is said to be complete if

For every RequestItem ri in r.request_item_set.all(); ri is complete

I need to filter out the requests which are complete/aren't complete.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking for. You want to get the number of donations required to fulfil all related `RequestItem`s?

Comment: No, I need to get the Request items for which all the RequestItems have their requirements fulfilled. To simplify, let's say Request A is connected to 2 RequestItems B and C. B is connected to a Donation D; and C is connected to Donations E and F. A will be said to be fulfilled/complete, if B.needed=D.donated and C.needed=E.donated+F.donated

Comment: Simplified the wording of the question as much as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure sum of 'donated' will never exceed value of 'needed' for every request item, you could do this way:

```
from django.db.models import Sum, F
Request.objects.annotate(needed=Sum('requestitem__needed', distinct=True), donated=Sum('requestitem__donation__donated')).filter(donated__gte=F('needed'))
```

Here sum of all donations per request is compared against sum of all 'needed' values for the same request. If former is greater or equivalent, request could be considered as completed

Comment: You need to pass `distinct=True` to the `needed` `Sum` otherwise multiple related `Donation`s will cause repeated sums